# Invalid input file upload api platform

Tags: reactjs, symfony, react-redux, redux-saga, api-platform.com

I'm trying to upload a file using [api platform file upload](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/). I'm using React-redux with redux-saga to make this request, but the server keeps throwing bad request response.

Api platform documentation says the following for making the request:

> This endpoint accepts standard multipart/form-data-encoded data, but
>   not JSON data. You will need to format your request accordingly.

**My Saga:**
I tried appending my uploaded file to `formData` and use that as body for my request.

```
 let data = new FormData();
 data.append("file", action.payload.file)

 const fileResponse = yield call(
   fetch,
   `${api.url}/api/media_objects`,
   {
     method: 'POST',
     mode: 'no-cors',
     body: data,
     headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
   }
 );
 return console.log(fileResponse);
```

This is the api platform example request for posting a new media object

> curl -X POST
>   "https://api.myroute/api/media_objects" -H
>   "accept: application/ld+json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
>   -F "file=@1.6b.jpg;type=image/jpeg"

Api platform keeps returning a 400 error, which refers to invalid input. Any idea how the valid input should look like?

For my media object entity I followed the [api platform documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/), so it looks exactly the same as in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Details matter

```
headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
```

It should be

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
```

There is no `'content-type'`, only `'Content-Type'` header is defined (RFC) and widely accpeted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue recently (I can't remember the exact error), with API Platform (and the MediaObject entity), and React - redux (but no redux-saga).

I was able to fix it by removing the header part of my request :

```
headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
```

So my new request looked exactly like that in my case :

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    return fetch(id, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    ...
```

I don't really know why, but it did the trick. Maybe it is handled automatically since we send a FormData object.

Hope it can work for you too !

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I already tried removing the header but it still throws the 400 error of invalid input, I tried the same in postman without the headers and it works there. Don't really know whats causing the issue